# How to save image in binary formate into database and also read data from database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-imageview, android-image

I want take image from camera then save image in SD card folder but path is save in SqLite database and also save image in binary format. Also when read from database then show image in ImageView or GridView. any have resource or example or tutorial links about this. If anybody give me any resource, or example or tutorial links. It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your task in three independent parts:

```
1. Take a picture from camera
2. Save it to a file and take the path
3. Store the path from point two in your database
```

For part 1 and 2:

```
final int IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA = 0;
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA);
```

In onActivityResult()...

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
String path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
}

...

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

For part 3 just write the string `path` the appropriate field in your database. For opening is easy, since you have the path, just open a stream from the path, do some conversions and get your image.